# Cholesky Decomposition L^T * L

Tags: numpy

I want to do the Cholesky decomposition but with a difference, I want A = L^T * L where L is the lower-triangular matrix, of course A is Hermitic and the eigenvalues are positive. I know that bouth ways are valid, but I don't know hot to do it. Where I can find the algorithm or the mathematical expression to do this or the library?

The numpy cholesky only return the L * L^T, and I don't want that case.

Edit 1.

I already solved the problem:

```py
import numpy as np

def contrary_cholesky_f(A):
    N = len(A)
    L = np.zeros_like(A, dtype = 'complex_')
    a = 0
    b = 0
    # print(N)
    for i in reversed(range(0,N)):
        # Diagonal element L_{i,i}
        a = 0
        # print(i)
        for k in range(i+1,N):
            a += np.conjugate(L[k, i]) * L[k, i]
            # print(a,k, L[k,i])
        L[i, i] = np.sqrt(A[i, i] - a)

        # Off-diagonal elements L_{i,j} for i > j
        for j in reversed(range(0, i)):
            b = 0
            # print(j)
            for k in range(i+1,N):
                b += np.conjugate(L[k, i]) * L[k, j]
            L[i, j] = (A[i, j] - b) / L[i, i]

    return L

# Example usage:
N = 3  # replace with the desired dimension size
A = np.array([[4, 12, -16],
              [12, 37, -43],
              [-16, -43, 98]], dtype=np.float64)


L1 = contrary_cholesky_f(A)
print(L1)
print(np.matmul(np.conj(L1.T),L1))
```

Comment: And this will not be Cholesky decomposition. Note that cholesky decomposition LL^T or U^TU is defined for positive definite matrices. which are practically symmetric. Cholesky decomposition is UNIQUE. Thus if you end up getting another L^TL for the same matrix, then than means you have 2 U^TU cholesky decompositions, making it not unique. But we know that Cholesky is unique. Thereby whatever you are asking for is impossible. eg find a number greater than 5 and at the same time less than 3 is what you are asking for

Comment: What I meant is to decompose the matrix in the form L^T*L, where L is the lower triangular. I just put Cholesky because is similar but I know that the form of Cholesky is L*L^T. I tried with these equations but is not working: L_{i,i} = \sqrt{A_{i,i} - \sum_{k=i+1}^{N} \overline{L_{k,i}} \cdot L_{k,i}} \\
L_{i,j} = \frac{A_{i,j} - \sum_{k=i+1}^{N} \overline{L_{k,i}} \cdot L_{k,j}}{L_{i,i}}

Comment: simply cannot happen. You can have `U^TU` but not L^TL. The equations do not matter. Well i encourage you to try asking the same on chatgtp

Comment: I did it with those equations, the important part is that the loop has to start with the last element L[N][N]